# export-modulemember powershell alias

Tags: powershell, alias

```
I wrote this module with powershell 5.1 under Win10

function GetUserInfo
{
    $user_name = $env:UserName
    $user_domain = $env:UserDomain
    $user_computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    $user_ip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($user_computer);
    $user_ip = $user_ip[1].IPAddressToString

    return $user_info = "$user_domain/$user_ip/$user_computer/$user_name"
}
export-modulemember -function GetUserInfo -Alias ee -Verbose
```

The output from the import-module is

```
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'GetUserInfo'.
```

But the Alias doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation on the [Export-ModuleMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet explain that -Alias parameter is used to export existing aliases in the module. It doesn't create aliases that don't exist.

Try adding:

```
New-Alias -Name ee -Value GetUserInfo
```

before your Export-ModuleMember statement

Comment: Yes, in conjunction with Export-ModuleMember -Alias it works. Now I decided to set all alias on one place with " new-item -path alias:sd -value GetUserInfo". If I do this I don't need the Alias on Export-ModuleMember.

Answer (score 3):

If creating new aliases with associated with your functions is what you are after, sure you can to it with the New-Alias item veefu points to, but did you know you can add your alias for a function in the function directly , like this

```
Function New-Function
{
    [CmdletBinding()]

    [Alias('EnterAliasName')]

    Param
    (

    )

    # Code begins here

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice, the alias is  defined at the function and can be exported afterwards.